# Encurtar chamada de método do Objeto

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Recentemente estava fazendo exercícios da faculdade, estamos vendo herança, e fiz um código que gerou muitas linhas para demonstrar que está funcionando a herança das classes, tem alguma forma de encurtar essas chamadas no fim do programa?

```
atleta1 = Atleta('Atleta', 'Não', 78)
atleta1.imprime()
atleta1.aposentar()
atleta1.aquecer()

corredor1 = Corredor('Corredor', 'Não', 66)
corredor1.imprime()
corredor1.aposentar()
corredor1.aquecer()
corredor1.correr()

nadador1 = Nadador('Nadador', 'Sim', 70)
nadador1.imprime()
nadador1.aposentar()
nadador1.aquecer()
nadador1.nadar()

ciclista1 = Ciclista('Ciclista', 'Sim', 76)
ciclista1.imprime()
ciclista1.aposentar()
ciclista1.aquecer()
ciclista1.pedalar()

triatleta1 = TriAtleta('TriAtleta', 'Não', 65)
triatleta1.imprime()
triatleta1.aposentar()
triatleta1.aquecer()
triatleta1.correr()
triatleta1.nadar()
triatleta1.pedalar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, criei algumas classes pra poder explicar alguns conceitos importantes.

A classe Atleta é a base onde terá os **atributos** e os **métodos comuns** em todas as outras classes.

```
class Atleta:
    def __init__(self, tipo, aposentado, idade):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.aposentado = aposentado
        self.idade = idade

    def imprime(self):
        print(f'Tipo: {self.tipo} | Aposentado: {self.aposentado} | Idade: {self.idade}')

    def aposentar(self):
        if self.aposentado == 'Não':
            if self.idade >= 65:
                self.aposentado = 'Sim'
                print(f'{self.tipo} de {self.idade} anos acabou de se aposentar!')
            else:
                print(f'{self.tipo} de {self.idade} anos ainda não tá na hora de se aposentar!')
        else:
            print(f'{self.tipo} de {self.idade} anos já é aposentado!')

    def aquecer(self):
        print(f'{self.tipo} de {self.idade} anos está aquecendo!')
```

Sendo assim, para criar uma outra classe personalizada, é passado como **herança** a classe Atleta e **herdada** seus métodos e atributos, restando apenas declarar o método responsável por esse tipo de Atleta.

```
class Corredor(Atleta):
    def __init__(self, tipo, aposentado, idade):
        super(Corredor, self).__init__(tipo, aposentado, idade)

    def correr(self):
        print(f'{self.tipo} de {self.idade} anos está correndo!')

class Nadador(Atleta):
    def __init__(self, tipo, aposentado, idade):
        super(Nadador, self).__init__(tipo, aposentado, idade)

    def nadar(self):
        print(f'{self.tipo} de {self.idade} anos está nadando!')

class Ciclista(Atleta):
    def __init__(self, tipo, aposentado, idade):
        super(Ciclista, self).__init__(tipo, aposentado, idade)

    def pedalar(self):
        print(f'{self.tipo} de {self.idade} anos está pedalando!')
```

É possível notar que TriAtleta herda as outras 3 classes, sendo assim, possível passar pra essa classe os **métodos únicos** de cada classe, isso é **reutilização de código**!

```
class TriAtleta(Corredor, Nadador, Ciclista):
    def __init__(self, tipo, aposentado, idade):
        super(TriAtleta, self).__init__(tipo, aposentado, idade)
```

Aqui é criado um dicionário com as devidas **ações como string** de cada tipo de classe, ou seja, se passar para as acoes um Atleta como parâmetro, é retornado ['imprime', 'aposentar', 'aquecer'].

```
acoes = {
    'Atleta': ['imprime', 'aposentar', 'aquecer'],
    'Corredor': ['imprime', 'aposentar', 'aquecer', 'correr'],
    'Nadador': ['imprime', 'aposentar', 'aquecer', 'nadar'],
    'Ciclista': ['imprime', 'aposentar', 'aquecer', 'pedalar'],
    'TriAtleta': ['imprime', 'aposentar', 'aquecer', 'correr', 'nadar', 'pedalar'],
}
```

Aqui são **Instanciadas** as Classes gerando o **Objeto** de cada tipo de atleta.

```
atleta = Atleta('Atleta', 'Não', 78)
corredor = Corredor('Corredor', 'Não', 66)
nadador = Nadador('Nadador', 'Sim', 70)
ciclista = Ciclista('Ciclista', 'Sim', 76)
triatleta = TriAtleta('TriAtleta', 'Não', 65)
```

Como o @epx bem comentou, é possível percorrer um **loop** por cada atleta e o outro loop é por cada **ação** desse determinado atleta. O método getattr chama a função com o nome de cada ação do atleta atual, se não achar o método, ele retorna uma função que retorna uma string vazia. Isso é **polimorfismo**.

```
for pessoa in [atleta, corredor, nadador, ciclista, triatleta]:
    for acao in acoes[pessoa.tipo]:
        getattr(pessoa, acao, lambda: '')()
```

**Referências**

> https://wiki.python.org.br/ProgramacaoOrientadaObjetoPython

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma menos repetitiva de verificar se as classes herdaram exatamente esses métodos é usar a função `hasattr` em cada objeto.

```py
acoes = ['imprime', 'aposentar', 'aquecer', 'correr', 'nadar', 'pedalar']

for pessoa in [atleta, corredor, nadador, ciclista, triatleta]:
    print(f'Objeto da classe: {type(pessoa)}')

    for acao in acoes:
        if hasattr(pessoa, acao):
            print(f'Possui o método {acao}')
        else:
            print(f'Não possui o método {acao}')

    print()
```

Ou, se você quiser verificar dinamicamente todos os métodos de um determinado objeto, use o `dir`.

```py
for pessoa in [atleta, corredor, nadador, ciclista, triatleta]:
    print(f'Lista de métodos do objeto da classe: {type(pessoa)}')

    for atributo in dir(pessoa):
        if not atributo.startswith('__') and callable(getattr(pessoa, atributo)):
            print(atributo)

    print()
```

Note que é preciso verificar se o atributo não começa com `__` (pois são os atributos reservados criados pelo próprio Python) e se o atributo é chamável (para só printar métodos, não propriedades).

Answer (score 0):

Encurtar de que forma? Uma possibilidade é fazer um loop com uma lista contento os objetos e chamar os métodos em comum que todos tê, algo como

```
for atleta in [atleta1, corredor1, nadador1, ...]:
    atleta.imprime()
    atleta.aposentar()
    ...
```

Outra coisa que você pode fazer é providenciar para que todas as chamadas retornem self, aí você poderia encadear horizontalmente:

```
atleta1.imprime().aposentar().aquecer()...
```